# Creating a new variable withing prolog program

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I have a question regarding the variable creating inside the program.
Lets say i have a function(?- not sure about the wording here), which is /2, is there a way of changing it to /1?

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
solve(N, L):-
        L = [A,B,C,D],
        L ins 1..sup,
        N #= A * B * C * D,
        all_distinct(L),
        A #< B, B #< C, C #< D,
        labeling([],L),nl,
        Z #= A+B+C+D,
        write(A+B+C+D=Z).
```

Is there a possibility of actually making it solve(N), where L is created on the run.
Tried using both,

```
L is [A,B,C,D],
```

or

```
L = [],
L is [A,B,C,D]
```

but no luck right now.

Program is working like that:->

```
 ?- solve(30,Elements).

1+2+3+5=11
Elements = [1, 2, 3, 5].

?-     solve(60, Elements).

1+2+3+10=16
Elements = [1, 2, 3, 10] ;

1+2+5+6=14
Elements = [1, 2, 5, 6] ;

1+3+4+5=13
Elements = [1, 3, 4, 5] ;
false.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but then you would get for example:

```
?- solve(30).

1+2+3+5=11
true.

?- solve(60).

1+2+3+10=16
true ;

1+2+5+6=14
true ;

1+3+4+5=13
true ;
false.
```

If this is what  you are looking for just write `solve(N)` instead `solve(N, L)`:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
solve(N):-
        L = [A,B,C,D],
        L ins 1..sup,
        N #= A * B * C * D,
        all_distinct(L),
        A #< B, B #< C, C #< D,
        labeling([],L),nl,
        Z #= A+B+C+D,
        write(A+B+C+D=Z).
```

Keep in mind that `L is [A,B,C,D]` is not valid because `is/1` is used for arithmetic expressions not unification. You need to use `=/2` which unifies L with a four element list.

If you want to print the list you could write:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
solve(N):-
        L = [A,B,C,D],
        L ins 1..sup,
        N #= A * B * C * D,
        all_distinct(L),
        A #< B, B #< C, C #< D,
        labeling([],L),nl,
        Z #= A+B+C+D,

        writeln(A+B+C+D=Z),
        write("Elements="),
        write(L).
```

Example:

```
?- solve(30).

1+2+3+5=11
Elements=[1,2,3,5]
true.
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing this with solve(N), but still showing the elements in list?

Comment: Only if you print the list (using write - to print each element of L).

Comment: Updated the answer to print the list

Comment: But how would I get rid of the true?, or if not that then the false in the end.

Comment: @EgertAia See the other answer as well: you really, really don't want to get rid of the `true`. This is how the top level tells you that your predicate succeeded. The only way to throw away all the good stuff that the top level is giving you is to write your own interpreter that you invoke from the command line directly.

Comment: I agree with Boris you can't get rid of true as you can't get rid of false in you second example when it has no more solutions...

Answer (score 2):

You can try to "hide" the output variable, and write it yourself, as you are already doing: just remove the second argument from the head of your predicate definition:

```
solve(N) :-
    % rest unchanged
```

Then:

```
?- solve(30).

1+2+3+5=11
true.
```

But this is really counter-productive. The "Prolog" way is to just use the top level for the printing. For example, I would completely remove the manual writing from your definition:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
solve(N, Z-L):-
        L = [A,B,C,D],
        L ins 1..sup,
        N #= A * B * C * D,
        all_distinct(L),
        A #< B, B #< C, C #< D,
        Z #= A+B+C+D,
        labeling([],L).
```

Then:

```
?- solve(30, Solution).
Solution = 11-[1, 2, 3, 5].
```

However, even this is suboptimal. It is better to leave the labeling outside of the predicate that poses the constraints:

```
solve(N, Z-L):-
        L = [A,B,C,D],
        L ins 1..sup,
        N #= A * B * C * D,
        all_distinct(L),
        A #< B, B #< C, C #< D,
        Z #= A+B+C+D.
```

If there are no residual constraints, you still get the solution immediately:

```
?- solve(30, Solution).
Solution = 11-[1, 2, 3, 5].
```

(We are not calling `labeling/2` at all any more!)

If you are particularly fond of the `A + B + ... = Sum` format of the solution, you can still let the top level do the printing for you. Just change the head of your predicate to:

```
solve(N, A+B+C+D=Z) :-
    % rest as in the last example
```

Then:

```
?- solve(30, Solution).
Solution =  (1+2+3+5=11).
```